# Can I insert an image into an equation?

Tags: math-mode, graphics, equations

I would like to use a small image in an equation, where a symbol like `\alpha` might otherwise be. Is there a nice way to do this?

Comment: I have never tried `\includegraphics` in math mode, but I would expect it to work. Are you saying it doesn't? Or is it that you have some difficulty with vertical alignment (which I imagine could become problematic)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It won't scale nicely with font size, but a simple approach is straightforward. 
The image should have a tight bounding box, which you can achieve with tools like pdfcrop.

```
\newcommand{\mysymbol}{\mathord{\includegraphics[height=1.6ex]{symbol}}}
```

`\mathord` is suitable for ordinary symbols, since you indicated that it would be used similarly as `\alpha`.

With the suggestions from the comments, I wrote a better solution.

```
\newcommand{\myfancysymbol}{
 {\mathchoice
  {\includegraphics[height=1.6ex]{symbol}}
  {\includegraphics[height=1.6ex]{symbol}}
  {\includegraphics[height=1.2ex]{symbol}}
  {\includegraphics[height=0.9ex]{symbol}}
 }
}
```

The symbol scales like a capital X for subscript and subsubscripts.

Comment: Use `height=1em`, then the picture can be auto scaled.

Comment: @Leo Liu: It should, but it didn't work in my tests: `$ \mysymbol_{\mysymbol_{\mysymbol}} $` gives 3x the same size with `1em` or similar.

Comment: Until someone suggest a nicer automatic scaling, I would still say a static 1em is nicer. Thanks Leo for the suggestion.

Comment: @Martin: Use `\mathchoice` then. I used this trick in my own document years ago.

Comment: I would suggest `1.6ex` instead, which is about the height of an uppercase `X`. The `1em` is actually the *width* of an uppercase `M`.

Comment: I agree with `1.6ex` or something similar. BTW, `1em` is in fact the length of `\quad`. It used to be width of `M`, but now don't have to.

Comment: I have incorporated all your comments to an improved solution.

Comment: @Mikael: Don't use braces outside `\mathord`, it will be wrong for `\mathbin` etc. And there're `\defaultscriptratio` and `\defaultscriptscriptratio` for scriptstyle and scriptscriptstyle. Or we can read the value set by `\DeclareMathSizes` before.

Comment: @Mikael, a tip: you can use backticks `\`` to mark your inline code as I did in my edit.

Comment: @Leo, You are right about \mathord, however i opted to remove it, as just as you've seen for yourself, it's necessary to beeing able to use it conveniently `X_\symbol`. I choose not to use use \defaultscriptratio, as I could not get it to work without involving the calc package, which felt like a unnecessary complication at this point. I have learnt alot on this question and I thank you all for the helpful comments.

Comment: @Mikael: If the symbol is `\mathbin`, we will use it as `$X_{a \foo b}$`. Mostly only ordinary symbols is used as `$X_\foo$`.

Comment: @Leo, yes, and as far as i can see, he do wants an ordinary symbol, like `\alpha`

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I wanted. I found that if I made the images 'bigger' than normal text, they would be vertically misplaced, so I used @TH's suggestion of `\vcenter` to get them better placed.

Comment: Note that I needed to add an additional pair of {} around the whole command definition in order to be able to use it as subscript as in $x_\myfancysymbol$.

Answer (score 7):

Mikael and Leo both gave good answers so I won't repeat that information.

If you need the image centered with respect to binary operators, fractions, and the like, then you can use `\vcenter{...}` to perform that vertical centering.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. There is nearly no difference between a image and a symbol. Just define a command for convenience. You can also use `PSTricks` or `TikZ` to draw such a symbol.

However, you may need to redefine the depth of the box, and refine the spacing using `\mathbin` etc.

A full example (suppose a `logo.pdf` exists):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\xlogo#1{\includegraphics[width=#1em]{logo}}
\def\logo{{% mathord
  \mathchoice
    {\xlogo1}%
    {\xlogo1}%
    {\xlogo\defaultscriptratio}%
    {\xlogo\defaultscriptscriptratio}}}
\begin{document}
$\logo_{\logo_{\logo_\logo}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems I'm too obstinate to use `ex`. :)