# Can I insert a vertically centered image in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, graphics, vertical-alignment

In Mikael Öhman's answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11069/can-i-insert-an-image-into-an-equation), he provides some code for placing an image in math mode as a symbol using the `\mathord` declaration.  I can define a new command in the preamble using this, and it works, but the image is placed on the baseline of the equation.

I want it to be a good deal taller than typical text, so ideally I could use `\vcenter` to center it vertically.  When I do include the centering, the image is treated as if it were as wide as the page, i.e. there are about 6 inches of white space following it.  (The image is closely cropped, so the white space is certainly created by LaTeX.

Where is the glitch in my code?

```
\newcommand{\bone}{\mathord{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{../images/dog_bone.pdf}}}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `\hbox` within `\vcenter`:

```
\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics{filename}}}
```

You could add `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}` to your macro definition if you always use it vertically centered.

Btw. generally you could simply use additional braces instead of `\mathord` to get the normal spacing.

Comment: I'm getting an error with it (in `LuaLaTeX`): `! Missing $ inserted. <inserted text>  $ l.415 \vcenter {\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{./figures/donkey}}}} ?`. Any idea how to solve?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty `\vcenter` requires math mode, so just put it in `$...$`.