# Alignment of math operators in table environment

Tags: tables, graphics

I have to reproduce a part of the following figure[image]

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]{example.pdf} =  &
    \includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]{example0.pdf} + &
    \includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]{example1.pdf} + &
    \includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]{example2.pdf} + &
                                +                     &
    \includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]{example3.pdf} +&
    \includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]{example4.pdf} +&
    \includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]{example5.pdf} +&
                                                      &
    \includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]{example6.pdf} +&
    \includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]{example7.pdf} +&  
    \includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]{example8.pdf} &
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{This is   some figure side by side}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I get the following output

[image]

I would like to know how I can alligh the math operators (+,=) so I can get them in the middle

Thanks and Regards,

Fowaz

Comment: Perhaps related http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12382/12571

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precise alignment to the plus sign is obtained by enveloping the `\includegraphics` in `\vcenter`, which is automatically done by `array` (since we're in math mode) without optional arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\vcenterincludegraphics}[2][]{%
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
  \end{array}%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering

$\begin{aligned}
  \vcenterincludegraphics[width=.20\textwidth]{example-image-1x1} ={}&
  \vcenterincludegraphics[width=.20\textwidth]{example-image-1x1} +
  \vcenterincludegraphics[width=.20\textwidth]{example-image-1x1} +
  \vcenterincludegraphics[width=.20\textwidth]{example-image-1x1} + {} \\
  &
  \vcenterincludegraphics[width=.20\textwidth]{example-image-1x1} +
  \vcenterincludegraphics[width=.20\textwidth]{example-image-1x1} +
  \vcenterincludegraphics[width=.20\textwidth]{example-image-1x1} + {} \\
  &
  \vcenterincludegraphics[width=.20\textwidth]{example-image-1x1} +
  \vcenterincludegraphics[width=.20\textwidth]{example-image-1x1} +
  \vcenterincludegraphics[width=.20\textwidth]{example-image-1x1}
\end{aligned}$

\caption{This is some figure side by side}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I changed `.23` to `.20` to avoid overfull lines (the code has been taken, with modifications, from Werner's answer).

[image]

Of course the definition

```
\newcommand{\vcenterincludegraphics}[2][]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
  }}%
}
```

would be more efficient, perhaps at the expense of clarity.

Answer (score 4):

I did several things.  I edited to force line breaks in the `tabular`, where appropriate, I used `\raisebox` to achieve vertical centering of math operators, which I also cast into math mode for proper spacing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\newcommand\IG[1]{\raisebox{-.5\height}{%
  \includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\tabcolsep0pt
\renewcommand\arraystretch{7}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}
    \IG{example.pdf}${}={}$&
    \IG{example0.pdf}${}+{}$&
    \IG{example1.pdf}${}+{}$&
    \IG{example2.pdf}${}+{}$\\&
    \IG{example3.pdf}${}+{}$&
    \IG{example4.pdf}${}+{}$&
    \IG{example5.pdf}${}+{}$\\&
    \IG{example6.pdf}${}+{}$&
    \IG{example7.pdf}${}+{}$&  
    \IG{example8.pdf} 
    \phantom{${}+{}$}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{This is   some figure side by side}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You may wish to set this like a regular equation, using [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)'s `valign=m` to set the images with a vertical anchor point in the `m`iddle:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\oldincludegraphics[valign=m,width=.23\textwidth,#1]{#2}}
  \begin{align*}
    \includegraphics{example-image-1x1} &=
    \includegraphics{example-image-1x1} +
    \includegraphics{example-image-1x1} +
    \includegraphics{example-image-1x1} + {} \\
    & \phantom{{}={}}
    \includegraphics{example-image-1x1} +
    \includegraphics{example-image-1x1} +
    \includegraphics{example-image-1x1} + {} \\
    & \phantom{{}={}}
    \includegraphics{example-image-1x1} +
    \includegraphics{example-image-1x1} +
    \includegraphics{example-image-1x1}
  \end{align*}
  \vspace{-\belowdisplayskip}
  \caption{This is some figure side by side}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The above approach mimics typical mathematical typesetting in terms of spacing around operators, seeing as your are doing exactly that.

Comment: Good answer, but I disagree with the idea of redefining `\includegraphics`, even locally.

Answer (score 3):

Similarly, but with help of `adjustbox` and `array package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}*{4}{p{0.23\textwidth}>{$}c<{$}}@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{example-image-a} &=&
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{example-image}   &+& 
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{example-image}   &+& 
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{example-image}   &+  \\[7ex]
%
    &   &
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{example-image}   &+&
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{example-image}   &+&
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{example-image}   &  \\
  \end{tabular}
 \caption{This is   some figure side by side}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use `\raisebox` on every "+"sign

```
\includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]{example.pdf} \raisebox{1.1cm}{=}  &
\includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]{example0.pdf} \raisebox{1.1cm}{+} &
\includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]{example1.pdf} \raisebox{1.1cm}{+} &
\includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]{example2.pdf} \raisebox{1.1cm}{+} &
                            \raisebox{1.1cm}{+}
```

You gotta iterate the height of the sign for different desired results.