# Inserting a picture in an equation

Tags: graphics, equations, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I insert an image into an equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11069/can-i-insert-an-image-into-an-equation)

Is there any method to insert a picture in an equation? I am trying to write an equation where one of the elements of the equation is a small image. I need to obtain a pattern like this:

2 * image1 + 3 * image2 = image3       (equation number)

Please note, one simple way is to make a figure and put all of these elements in it and use \includegraphics to load it into LaTeX document as a figure, however, I need to have an equation with the above structure, not a figure.

Comment: I answered below but I think the referenced question is essentially a duplicate. If the answers there solve your problem we'll close this one as duplicate/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `\includegraphics` in math mode.

so

```
\begin{equation}
2*\includegraphics{image1} + 3*\includegraphics{image2} = \includegraphics{image3}
\end{equatioon}
```

Comment: I need to be able to adjust the position. How can I make the center of the figure along the text line?

Comment: Any mechanism for moving a box would work, perhaps the `adjustbox` package is the easiest.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle An example would be super helpful.

Comment: @DoctorMohawk better to ask a new question than comment on old answers but basically `adjustbox` package lets you go `\includegraphics[valign=c]{...}` to get a vertically centred image.

Comment: More precisely `\adjincludegraphics[valign=c]{...}`

Comment: @SphericalTriangle I'd recommend loading `adjustbox` with the `export` option so the keys are added to the standard `\includegraphics` command,