# How to align an inserted image within equation

Tags: graphics, equations, vertical-alignment

This question has been asked before [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79096/inserting-a-picture-in-an-equation) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11069/can-i-insert-an-image-into-an-equation?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I am struggling to make things perfectly work.

I am using `beamer`, but I guess that does not matter.

This is my code:

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{How is it used?}
\justifying
\footnotesize
$$f\left(\adjincludegraphics[valign=c,height=1cm]{cat.jpg} \right)$$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result is this:

[image]

As you can see, the parenthesis are not perfectly aligned with the image. I admit I am being nitpicky, but one of the nice things about LaTeX is that you can afford to be like that. I attached the image I am using for reference here:

[image]

Comment: See [Why is `\[` ... `\]` preferable to `$$` ... `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)

Comment: that did not change anything, but I'll take that into account,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just fiddle with the `raise` and `set vsize` options from the `adjustbox` package until you are happy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\[
  f\left(\adjincludegraphics[valign=c, height=1cm, raise=0.2\baselineskip,
    set vsize={1.3cm}{0cm}]{example-image} \right)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Perhaps a relative `raise` would be more appropriate (something like `raise=.2\baselineskip`)?